# Pandas map --- ValueError: Length mismatch

Tags: python, pandas

I have two CSVs in memory stored as dataframes: df1 and df2

df1 has a column 'OOSCUSTID'
df2 has a column 'FORCUSTID'

For each row in df1:

Where the OOSCUSTID value in df1 == FORCUSTID value in df2, take the value from df2['KKLM'], and store it in df1['FOREIGN-KKLM'']

```
df1:

NO.     OOSCUSTID   # TRADES    AVG PROFIT/LOSS
648500  -17         103         1305914.12
648483  -16         103         1305914.12
648502  -15         103         1305914.12

df2:

NO. FORCUSTID   KKLM    AVG PROFIT/LOSS
648495  0       6   1305914.12
648500  -17     3   1305914.12
648483  -16     5   1305914.12
648502  -15     6   1305914.12
648484  -14     7   1305914.12
648482  -13     8   1305914.12
648501  -12    20.34    1305914.12
648486  -9    4534  1305914.12
648487  -8    103   1305914.12
```

The code below produces error:

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected 9 rows, received array of length 1

```
checkstats = ["FOREIGN-KKLM"]
c = ["KKLM"]
ooscolfor = ["FORCUSTID"]
ooscolmain = ["OOSCUSTID"]

df1[checkstats] = df2.set_index([ooscolfor])[c].reindex(df1[ooscolmain]).array
```

**EDIT 2**
Amending df1 and df2 and using the code:

```
df1['FOREIGN-KKLM'] = df1.merge(df2, left_on='OOSCUSTID', 
                                    right_on='FORCUSTID')['KKLM']
```

Produces an inconsistency - When #3 should be Nan and #4 should 4534:

```
      NO.  OOSCUSTID  # TRADES  AVG PROFIT/LOSS  FOREIGN-KKLM
0  648500        -17       103       1305914.12           3.0
1  648483        -16       103       1305914.12           5.0
2  648502        -15       103       1305914.12           6.0
3     545          4        44            44.00        4534.0
4      22         -9        22            22.00           NaN
```

Amended df's:

```
df1:

NO.     OOSCUSTID   # TRADES    AVG PROFIT/LOSS
648500  -17         103         1305914.12
648483  -16         103         1305914.12
648502  -15         103         1305914.12
545     4           44          44
22      -9          22          22

df2:

NO. FORCUSTID   KKLM    AVG PROFIT/LOSS
648495  0       6   1305914.12
648500  -17     3   1305914.12
648483  -16     5   1305914.12
648502  -15     6   1305914.12
648484  -14     7   1305914.12
648482  -13     8   1305914.12
648501  -12    20.34    1305914.12
648486  -9    4534  1305914.12
648487  -8    103   1305914.12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **`merge()`** method:

```
df1['FOREIGN-KKLM'] = df1.merge(df2, left_on='OOSCUSTID', 
                                    right_on='FORCUSTID',
                                     how='left')['KKLM']

Print(df1)
      NO.  OOSCUSTID  FOREIGN-KKLM
0  648500        -17           3.0
1  648483        -16           5.0
2  648502        -15           6.0
3     545          4           NaN
4      22         -9        4534.0
```

Comment: This does not work fully - see Edit#2 for the error.

Comment: I edited my answer. Basically, you just need to add `how = 'left'` parameter to `merge()` method. Please let me know how it works.